# (JGraphX) How to add an extra label to a vertex?

Tags: java, jgraphx

I have a vertex and it has its name, the label inside the vertex. But I also wan't to add a new label, with extra information, for the same vertex. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you need only a "static label" you could use a "stencil".

The [Stencils.java](https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx/blob/master/examples/com/mxgraph/examples/swing/Stencils.java) example program has some multi-label shapes.

If however you want more control on the content you want to show in the label, I could not find any "official" documentation: you might want to look at the examples I've added to [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445604/how-to-create-complex-multi-value-nodes-in-jgraphx).

Here are the direct links to the examples:

[An example of a multi-value node in JGraphX using "child nodes"](https://gist.github.com/insac/e56cb6cc5449acad1c0a70cee6f68531)

Here I've created child nodes and "locked" them to a parent/container node, by setting relative coordinates.

[An example of a multi-value node in JGraphX using "custom shape"](https://gist.github.com/insac/5fc487ee2e2d7d43e094316af493e176)

Here I've created a "custom shape" to access the Graphics2D awt object and be able to draw my shape and labels.